# HTML Select menu dropdown: from right to left

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the HTML select menu's dropdown start from right and flow towards left. Just like the one here - http://www.flipkart.com/ But its not happening. Its currently starting from left and flowing towards right. And in IE, the dropdown menu is getting hidden.

Code -

```
<div class="search fr curves3">  
    <input class="main_search curves3" type="text" value="" placeholder="Search for items">
    <span style="border-left:1px solid #999; float:left;">
    <select>
        <option>All Categories</option>
        <option>Cat</option>
        <option>Dog</option>
        <option>Bird Categories Categories Categories</option>
        <option>Aquatics</option>
    </select>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="Search">
</div>
```

CSS -

```
.search {
border:1px solid #999;
}
.search .main_search {
float:left;
padding: 7px 0 7px 5px;
border:0;
outline:none;
margin:0;
}
.search select {
float:left;
border:0;
outline:none;
padding: 7px 10px 7px 10px;
margin:0;
width:130px;
}
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/generalsagar/gQxR7/

So how to make the dropdown start from right and then flow towards left? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use `absolute` positioning. Your css for search box will be something like this

```
.search {
    border:1px solid #999;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gQxR7/6/)

Comment: In IE, the dropdown too is getting the same width as the select. So half of it is getting hidden.

Comment: @SagarRaj for browser compatibility issues related to IE, you can use **html5shiv.js**, you can download it from [here](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and also don't forget to add **reset.css** before your custom css file that you will get [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/). Hope this will help you.